# Rules .htaccess to redirect from http://miodominio.it to https://www.miodominio.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl

I have to domains:
miodominio.it
miodominio.com

The ".com" is under an SSL certificate. Now I want to redirect every call from the ".it" to the ".com" but the SSL certificate is valid only for the ".com".

I use those rules in my .htaccess:

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^miodominio\.it$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.miodominio\.it$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.miodominio\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Anyway when I go to this link: https://miodominio.it/ it's not redirected to https://www.miodominio.com and it gives me a privacy error.

What's the correct rule I should use to redirect it correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. From https to http (like in your comment):
   This rule redirects every request to example.com.

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
   RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   ```

or just for your example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.it 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

2. From http to https (like in your title):

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.it.com$ [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exp.it$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule (.*) https://www.exp.com/$1 [R=301,L]
   ```

....

Comment: Hi Madalina, thanks for your reply. Unfortunatly it seems not working. The link with httpS://www.miodominio.it is not redirected to https://www.miodominio.com

Comment: @Francesco Try now please. I think from https to http is RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on.

Comment: @Francesco Edit your title please. It is from https to http or from http to https?

Comment: Hi Madalina, I've tested again your solution without success. I want to redirect every "miodominio.it" to "miodominio.com" the problem is that if I type "https://miodominio.it" it do not redirects to "https://www.miodominio.com". Note that the ".it" is not under an SSL certificate.

Comment: https : // miodominio . it do NOT redirects to https : // www . miodominio . com

Comment: Well, I really think the code is ok. I don't know what you added more and how I can help you.

Comment: Ijust added the code you suggested me, nothing else. Thanks so much anyway Madalina!